# nested list with multiple conditions

Tags: python, nested-lists

Trying to create a list of tuples like so:

```
 m=[-1,0,1]
 [(self._x+x,self._y) for x in m for y in m]
```

But I want to exclude the tuple when both x and y are equal to 0. I've tried:

```
[(self._x+x,self._y) for x in m for y in m if x!=0 and y!=0]
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't create nested lists, it just creates one list. If you want nested lists, you need nested list comprehensions.

Comment: @Barmar You're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = [-1, 0, 1]

# so you want all combinations x and y out of m 
# but only if x and y are not both 0 at the same time?
[ (x, y) for x in m for y in m if not (x == 0 and y == 0) ]
## =>  [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Your code's problem are the `self.` - which occurs only within class definitions.
`self._x + x` is `x` from the for loop plus a certain `self._x` value, whatever that is. `self._y` is not y.
What you want with this actually? you don't use `y` from the second `for` loop at all in your code.